# Add TextBox to Telerik ConfirmationDialogType

Tags: c#, telerik

I hope someone can help me. I have this piece of Telerik code, although it works, I want to add a textbox to the confirmation window so that the user can add comment before clicking OK, or simply just cancel.

How do I add a textbox to that confirmation Radwindow?

```
   <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" HeaderText="<%$Resources:Resource, myButton %>"
          ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ConfirmText="<%$ Resources:DeleteConfirmation %>" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
           CommandName="Delete" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ImageUrl="~\images\App\delete.png">
    </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

Comment: I think you need to go with a custom button to use the prompt control and then update the record added invoke delete command

Comment: @rdmptn, thanks for the contribution but I don't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: I don't remember the API, is has been years. You can have your own button, trigger a prompt client side, send that data to the server, do the database operation.